# List the files that I can read

Tags: bash, unix, permissions

I would like to list any files that can be read by my current user in bash.
I'm not sure what would be the best way to check for that. I'm thinking something along the lines of  `ls -l | grep <myusername>|<mygroupname>` or `find .`, but that doesn't deal with the other permissions.

Also, I'm working on NetBSD box.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Does `find . -readable` exists in NetBSD?

Comment: @Ingaz there is no -readable flag. All bsd flags are a single character. no long options.

Comment: openbsd and netbsd seems to use the same find, which support a `-perm` flag that you can provide the permissions mode you want in octal : `https://man.openbsd.org/find#-perm`

Comment: Hm.  [Looks like](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?find+1+NetBSD-current)   `find . -perm /+r` must be available. Not sure about format of perm

Comment: @HSchmale I'm curious: how did you solve problem? (I have an interest for BSD-family OSes)

Comment: @Ingaz I didn't I got distracted. But on netbsd, -perm doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the 2 files below, where one can be read by user, and the other can't:

```
[fsilveir@fsilveir tmp]$ ls -l ./test_dir/can_read.txt ./test_dir/cant_read.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 861784 May 29 20:34 ./test_dir/can_read.txt
-rwx------. 1 root root      0 May 29 20:30 ./test_dir/cant_read.txt
```

You can use `find` with `-perm` option. By using `+r` you'll list the files you can read, and using `-r` for finding the ones you can't read, as shown below:

```
[fsilveir@fsilveir tmp]$ find . -name "*.txt" -perm -g+r 2>/dev/null
./test_dir/can_read.txt
[fsilveir@fsilveir tmp]$
```

Another approach is using `find` with `-readable` option, as shown below:

```
[fsilveir@fsilveir tmp]$ find . -name "*.txt" -readable
./test_dir/can_read.txt

[fsilveir@fsilveir tmp]$ find . -name "*.txt" ! -readable
./test_dir/cant_read.txt
```